# Visio 2010 Beta -- Where is the toolbar with the shapes?

Tags: microsoft-visio, office-2010-beta

This is driving me nuts, I can't find it.

I specifically mean these shapes:

[image]

Is there a shortcut key to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Home Tab in the Tools Group there is a drop down (top right of the group here) which contains the basic rectangle, ellipse and line tools.

The help includes the following keyboard shortcuts:

Select the Rectangle Tool:  CTRL+8

Select the Ellipse Tool: CTRL+9

Select the Line Tool: CTRL+6

Select the Arc Tool: CTRL+7

Select the Freeform Tool: CTRL+5

Select the Pencil Tool: CTRL+4

But I cannot see freeform drawing or arc in the ribbon (perhaps time for some product feedback).

Comment: Yeah, but what about the standard flowchart shapes such as these http://www.visguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/multi-shapes-flowchart.png  ?

Comment: I just created a drawing with the basic flowchart template, and the flowchart shapes are there. You can also click on more shapes to open any stencils.